# AVPlayer full screen issue only for iPhone x

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, swift4, avplayerviewcontroller

I created a splash video using Av player view controller. its is coming properly for all the devices except I Phone X. I tried changing video gravity frame and everything but it won't work. any Idea about this? here is the sample code :

```
guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Redtaxi-splash", ofType:"mov") else {
    return
}

let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController?.player = player
playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = false
playerViewController?.view.frame = view.frame
playerViewController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
playerViewController?.view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

view.addSubview((playerViewController?.view)!)
playerViewController?.player?.play()
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout or code, to handle UI?

Comment: To make sure that got your issue, how it looks like on the iPhone X (what's the exact issue)?

Comment: @iDeveloper based on `playerViewController?.view.frame = view.frame` it seems that he is not :)

Comment: @AhmadF Actually, he just updated the code  Now I can see 

Comment: @AhmadF for iPhone X its showing black at the top and the bottom of the screen..but it is working fine for other devices..

Comment: @Shibilik.p Can you please post some screenshots ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed this by giving the video gravity for the player view controller :

```
playerViewController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

this will fix the issue  by using the video gravity as aspect fill for the avplayer view controller. here is the documentation for video gravity:

> The video gravity determines how the video content is scaled or stretched within the player layer’s bounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
```